# Error in Django: Using the URLconf defined in django_test.urls, Django-3 tried these URL patterns, in this order:

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework

I've tried setting these URL's in this project, but I get a 404 when trying to access the registration.html file and the api-auth URL that is related to a REST API

[image: Error when accessing localhost:8000/registration]
[image: Error when accessing localhost:8000/api-auth]

For reference:

1. index = app
2. django_test = site

index/urls.py

```
from django.urls import include, path
from rest_framework import routers
from . import views

router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'users', views.UserViewSet)

# Wire up our API using automatic URL routing.
# Additionally, we include login URLs for the browsable API.
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.homepage, name="homepage"),
    path('/register', views.registration, name="registration"),
    path('api', include(router.urls)),
    path('api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace="rest framework")),
]
```

django_test/urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('index.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls)
]
```

index/views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
def homepage(request):
    return render(request,"home/homepage.html")

def registration(request):
    return render(request, 'home/registration.html')
```

All of our HTML files are located in index/templates/home directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try changing name="registration" to name="register" ?

Comment: It worked for the register, what about the api-auth?

Comment: Okay please try to change 'api-auth/' to '/api-auth/' in path('api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace="rest framework")),

Comment: Just tried it, still getting the 404 error

Comment: Okay my last advice will be to change it to '/api-auth' , so just remove the slash from the end :D I hope it helps!!

Answer (score 0):

Change the URL "register/" to "/registration"

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).